# How to change image size in amp-image-lightbox? (not maximizing up to window's edge)

Tags: amp-html

I want to edit amp-image-lightbox's style.
I want to give padding around image.
How can I do this?
Please help me.
(I'm sorry for my poor English..)

[image: not maximizing. padding around image.]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `padding` to the `<div>` tags

An example would be:

```
<div style="padding: 10px">
    <amp-img on="tap:lightbox1"
             role="button"
             tabindex="0"
             src="/static/samples/img/Border_Collie.jpg"
             alt="Picture of a dog"
             title="Picture of a dog, view in lightbox"
             layout="responsive"
             width="300" height="246"></amp-img>
    <amp-image-lightbox id="lightbox1" layout="nodisplay"></amp-image-lightbox>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use `style=` on an HTML element in AMP?

Comment: I only tried using the [AMP playground](https://playground.amp.dev/) and it seemed to give the desired result, so I thought it could be used.